# Silent AutoUpdate non-playstore Android App

Tags: android

I am developing a kiosk app which will run a Android tablets installed in remote locations. The devices will be locked down to ensure the users can only access the kiosk app.

To prevent the competition from seeing the app, the kiosk app can not be published on the Play Store.

I need a way for the kiosk app to automatically update silently, without using the Play Store. I understand that I need to root the devices which I don't think is a problem.

Please can someone recommend any easy solution for silently updating an app on a rooted device?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google store has its own privileges. If you try to publish an application on the Android store, first of all, it is needed to be analysis by google store and it is required to understand whether or not it needs additional permission(s) or outlaw actions on the application. If you make your own google store which leads you to not intervein in any authorities to prevent you from doing any action whatever you want. That is why you have no easy way to update applications silently. If there is anyway. It must be very difficult or extraordinary.

Comment: I'm not creating my own google store. I'm installing one app on devices owned by the company I work for and need a way to remotely update the app on those devices without interaction by the user.

Comment: we speak the same language of different ways. In brief, It is not possible to update application without inform user as google store does.